# Angular UI-Router doesn't match a defined state

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `UI-Router` module for routing. I have 2 states that router should match the urls with them :

```
// Dashboard
.state('dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "dashboard/views/index.html",
    controller: "DashboardController",
    ...
})

// Users
.state('users', {
    url: "/users",
    templateUrl: "users/views/index.html",
    controller: "UsersController",
    ...
})

// Single User
.state('users.id', {
    url: "/{id:^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$}",
    templateUrl: "users/views/show.html",
    controller: "UserController",
    ...
})
```

also I have set a default route :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
```

I want the router to match **users** `state` when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/#/users`

and to match **user** `state` when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/#/users/testuser`

**Problem :**

the users state works good, but the user state url doesn't get matched and redirects to the default state. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kLygXOGwtmQtsuhsdzzL?p=preview)

Try to use this *regex* def:

```
  .state('users.id', { 
      url: "/{id:(?:[a-z0-9_-]{3,16})}",
```

These links will work

```
  <a href="#/users">
  <a href="#/users/testuser">
```

This will go to otherwise

```
  <a href="#/users/xx">
```

Some inspiration could be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477045/1679310)

In case, we want to go to state 'users.id' directly, we just have to use proper call. In [this extended plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LbVIkEE8jNY79cfPOz2b?p=preview), we can see that it could be done like this:

```
// working
<a ui-sref="users">
<a ui-sref="users.id({id:'testword'})">
// not working - id does not fit - otherwise is used
<a ui-sref="users.id({id:'not-working simply too long'})">
```

The same would be with **`$state.go('users.id', {id:'testword'})`**

Check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477045/1679310)

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work when I want to go to the users.id state directly not via anchor.

Comment: I updated the answer, added more details, extended the plunker. Hope now you should have your answer ;) Good luck with UI-Router

Comment: thanks for the fast work, but the new problem is that `users.id` state loads `users` state **templateUrl** view. can you help sir?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I've done it in the past. Maybe it will help you.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
        function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$rootScope,$cookieStore) {
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
            $stateProvider
              .state('login', {
                  url: '/login',
                  title: 'Login',
                  templateUrl:'views/loginView.html',
                  controller: 'loginCtrl',
                  resolve: resolver($rootScope),

              })
              .state('account', {
                  url: '/account',
                  title: 'My Account',
                  accessLevel: 2,
                  resolve: resolver($rootScope,$cookieStore),   
                  views: {
                    'navigation': {
                         templateUrl: 'views/navigationView.html',
                         controller: 'navigationCtrl'
                    },
                    'content': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/contentView.html',
                        controller: 'navigationCtrl'
                    }
                 }            
              })
              .state('account.dashboard', {
                 url:'/dashboard',
                 title: 'Dashboard',
                 views : {
                    'pageContent': {
                        templateUrl:'views/dashboardView.html',
                        controller: 'dashboardCtrl'
                    }   
                 }             
              })
              .state('account.foo', {
                 url:'/foo',
                 title: 'foo',
                 views : {
                    'pageContent': {
                        templateUrl:'views/foo.html',
                        controller: 'fooCtrl'
                    }   
                 }             
              })
              .state('account.maps', {
                 url:'/maps',
                 title: 'Maps and stuff',
                 views : {
                    'pageContent': {
                        templateUrl:'views/mapsView.html',
                        controller: 'mapsCtrl'
                    }   
                 }             
              })

      }])
```