# Otherwise for states with typed parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I started using typed parameters (such as `{id:int}`) in my route configuration. If a state doesn't match **because of the type**, `otherwise` does not appear to trigger.

For example:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('stuff', {
        url: '/version/{version:int}/stuff',
        templateUrl: // ...,
        controller: // ...
    })
    .state('list', {
        url: '/list',
        // ...
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
```

If the version is "x" (not an int), I am not redirected to the list page. Instead I end up on an empty page with no errors in the console.

How can I fix this?

(Clarification: I'm typing in invalid URLs in the address bar to test this, not using `ui-sref`.)

**Update:** I believe I've found what's causing it (thanks to @RadimKöhler for an example that eliminated some possibilities). See my [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BlqYEN?p=preview).

Everything works fine **except** for URLs that fail to match a custom type built with `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.type()`. I used a `guid` type based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475790/how-to-add-guid-regex-in-angular-ui-router-state).

I can work around this by using regular expressions in the URL, but it would be nice to have a fix.

**More info:** Adding `pattern` to the custom [Type object](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.type:Type) appears to fix this. The pattern has to leave out the anchors (`^$`), so something like:

```
pattern: /[a-f\d]{8}-(?:[a-f\d]{4}-){3}[a-f\d]{12}/i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, that the concept as you wanted, is working. There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGx6BnffsdxoEmXPveFR?p=preview)

this state def *(1:1 to question)*

```
$stateProvider
  .state('stuff', {
    url: '/version/{version:int}/stuff',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    controller: 'StuffCtrl',
  })
  .state('list', {
    url: '/list',
    templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
    controller: 'ListCtrl',
  });


$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/list');
```

will properly handle these links:

```
// list
<a href="#/list">

// ui-sref
<a ui-sref="stuff({version:1})">
<a ui-sref="stuff({version:2})">

// href
<a href="#/version/12/stuff">
```

these will not work *(as expected)* - so they will not created any href *(such state with such params does not exist)*

```
<a ui-sref="stuff({version:'A'})">
<a ui-sref="stuff({version:'xyz'})">
```

these **`href`** will be redirect to otherwise

```
<a href="#/version/x/stuff">
<a href="#/version/AB/stuff">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RGx6BnffsdxoEmXPveFR?p=preview)

Comment: To play with the plunker in address bar try this http://run.plnkr.co/FGHZTs8XtxMwU0wW/#/version/123/stuff .. working one, while that http://run.plnkr.co/FGHZTs8XtxMwU0wW/#/version/ABC/stuff (check the ABC) is redirecting to /list

Comment: I narrowed down the issue thanks to you; it appears to be related to using custom types. If you have time please see my edit/plunk.